# Dask groupby on Futures

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I have scattered data on the cluster and submitted a task. How do I wait until all futures are finished and do a groupby on futures. i don't want to collect all the futures back to client as they are large. I want all the large futures stay on cluster and return the result from groupby to the client.
I tried pandas groupby syntax on the futures but it says it is not a method on futures. I am looking at using submit but can't figure out the syntax.

Thanks

```py
def repeat (df, number):
    df=pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df.values,number,axis=0))
    return df

data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random_sample((100,), columns=["test"])
data = client.scatter(data)
futures = client.submit(repeat, data, 1000)
data = client.gather(futures)
```

So far this is ok. But now I want the results stays on the workers and do the following pandas oeprations:

```py
data["ids"] = data.groupby(["test"]).cumcount()
total = data.groupby(["test"]).sum()
P10 = data.groupby(["test"]).quantile(0.1)
```

I would like to do this because the Dataframe Data is very large and will only fit on multiple workers. All I wanted to return is a aggregate of Data (i.e. groupby)

Thanks
EDIT
id column is the cumcount of a grouped test column. Basically I would like to do a monte carlo simulation on multiple points. The starting df contains row corresponding to each point. Then it is send to dask, each row will multiply by a 1000 times to simulate 1000 simulation trials. The ids is to track the trial number (1000 of them) and later I can group by id to get aggregate results for each trials for all the points together. For now, the sample code shows groupby test which is the aggregate for each row (data point). i.e. mean and P10 for each point within that 1000 trials

Comment: Do you mind to share a [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Comment: Sorry. I have just added this

Comment: Where is the id column? What is this line? `P10 = total = data.groupby(["test"]).quantile(0.1)`

Comment: I have amended the code. id column is the cumcount of a grouped test column. Basically I would like to do a monte carlo simulation on multiple points. The starting df contains row corresponding to each point. Then it is send to dask, each row will multiply by a 1000 times to simulate 1000 simulation trials. The ids is the track the trail number (1000 of them) and later I can group by id to get aggregate results for each trials for all the points. For now, the sample code shows groupby test which is the aggregate for each row (data point)